# Вывод картинок для новостей

Tags: php, mysql, sql

## Помогите с Новостями на своем мини-блоге!

**Мне нужна помощь, Как сделать так, чтобы изображение "***для новости***" Можно было загрузить на сам сайт**

- *P.s. У меня уже есть вариант, для этого в базу нужно добавить ссылку из интернета на эту картинку  затем с помощью* ***echo '[img src="'.$result['img'].'"]'*** *Но это не удобно*

Answer (score 0):

Если ваш проект маленький, в принципе можно помещать картинки в базу данных методом `blob`, но если он будет более масштабный, плюс ко всему новостной, вы можете реализовать изображения так, чтобы в базе данных хранились только пути, потом там где надо выводить изображения вы просто достаете из базы путь, а сами изображения лежат у вас на сервере по тем путям которые сохранены в базе.

То есть когда вы создаете статью, вы пишите текст, добавляете фото, на сервере вы сохраняете это фото например в папку `image` а потом в БД сохраняете путь к файлу и текст.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Правда я ожидал другой ответ, но тоже сойдет. Еще вопрос: Путь к файлу можно хранить той же ссылкой.

Comment: Какой угодно ссылкой можно хранить, главное чтобы эта ссылка возвращала тот файл что надо. Можно абсолютной, можно **HTTP** ссылкой, можно вообще виртуальной.